# API Call Field Update error

Tags: soap-api

Trying to update the SicDesc field from another system using API on Account. But run into this error.
INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE: Account: bad field names on insert/update call : SicDesc.
It works for Sic Code, but not the description.

Have checked visibility, FLS and the profile. In fact, tried the same upsert call for the same record using data loader with the same user and it worked alright. Any pointers would help.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Please add detail of the object model for these fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely an API version error. This field was introduced in API v24.0. Using an older version of the API, you won't be able to see this field (query, insert, update, etc). You need to upgrade your API version on the other system.

[image: API v23.0 vs API v24.0]